# How to speed up mysql sql when using complex sql with LIMIT?

Tags: mysql

My explain SELECT looks like :

[image]

```
rows: 111660; extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

The select (complex one) uses LIMIT 100 : it means it selects 100 rows.
However the explain SELECT shows there are more than 110,000 rows that match

Does mysql work that way: it selects all the 110,000 that match, then retries the top 100 with limit 100 ?

Is there a way to speed it ? (not retrieving 110,000 but just the first 100 that match ?)

regards

Comment: Please show your query.

Comment: it is generated by ORM and it makes like 8 pages. It is unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understand what you mean.
You need only a Sub Query

SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        Orders
    LIMIT 100) AS T

You can also use temporary table [link here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-temporary-table.html)